Help asking a question
I would like to ask what is the opposite of egocentrism and if someone who is never speaking of himself and present himself as very altruistic can be egocentric as well. My whole question is: can exist a correlation between idealists and the narcissistic trait?
The narcissism comes from denying any human fragility and imperfection. Altruism could be considered as: "I am a good person caring of others" and often people which are very empathetic experienced suffering.
Who has an open wound can become strongly lacking of empathy on some topics.. but how could I formulate the question in a better neutral way?

Pick one question and do some background research!
Which one of the following is the one you are interested in? If you do not yet have an answer, don't start spin-off questions.

"what is the opposite of egocentrism"
"[can] someone who is never speaking of himself and present himself as very altruistic [-] be egocentric"
"can [there] exist a correlation between idealists and the narcissistic trait?"

